# mysql group by column name except same id

Tags: mysql, database

I need to group a result by customer name where customer id's are not same.

```
select name , group_concat(cust_id) from customer group by name;
```

This is the query but I dont want to group name where cust_id's are not same. 
Eg

```
   Name      | Id
   Customer1 | 1,2,3
   Customer1 | 1
   Customer2 | 4
```

Above table record 1,2 having same name but same id's so they are not grouped.I need result like this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
    select name , group_concat(cust_id) from(select name,cust_id from customer 
group by name,cust_id)a group by name;
```

Comment: @SharavanakumaarMurugesan it may problem of space in name

Comment: It was grouping all the customers having same name. But I dont want to group name where customers having same Id. group by name where customer id is not same one